# How to put checkboxes in a row in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

```
               <div class="">
                    <input type="checkbox">a</div>
                <div class="">
                    <input type="checkbox">b</div>
                <div class="">
                    <input type="checkbox">c</div>
```

Right now, the code above displays all the checkbox in a vertical fashion. I want to be able to have them in rows, and when it runs out of space on one row, it would automatically jump over to the next row.

Comment: You could not wrap your inputs at all or you can use a `<span>` tag instead as it's default display is `inline`.

Answer (score 4):

Divs are block elements, and automatically move to their own line. Unless you have a need for that structure, you can just remove the divs completely and it will work. If you do need that structure, you can change it to inline-block.

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class=""><input type="checkbox">a</div>
<div class=""><input type="checkbox">b</div>
<div class=""><input type="checkbox">c</div>
```